# Cordova: clean way to check if user has enabled push notifications

Tags: ios, cordova, push-notification

Seems like there is probably an existing cordova solution for this, but I can't find it other than the cordovaBadge plugin 
- https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-badge
- http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/badge/

Problem is I have had to remove this plugin due to conflicts with LocalNotifications. (Seems like I can't have them both)

The cordovaBadge has a simple .hasPermission() method. Is there anything else in the cordova library that can do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use the [`isRemoteNotificationsEnabled()`](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin#isremotenotificationsenabled) method of [cordova-diagnostic-plugin](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin):

```
cordova.plugins.diagnostic.isRemoteNotificationsEnabled(function(isEnabled){
    console.log("Push notifications are " + (isEnabled ? "enabled" : "disabled"));
}, function(error){
    console.error("An error occurred: "+error);
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution is iOS only

Comment: yes anyone know any way to check the same for android ??

Comment: Do you need to know for Android I think it's only possible to block showing of notifications on Android not the actual push notification itself?

Comment: The plugin has been updated since this answer was posted: `isRemoteNotificationsEnabled()` is now supported on both Android and iOS.

Comment: Strangely, this returns true every time, even if the permission asking popup wasn't even displayed yet (on Oreo)

Comment: I can confirm this plugin is working in iOS 12.1.4 and with Cordova 8.1.2 Thank you @DaveAlden

Answer (score 0):

Dear @vargen_ you're right!

I'm using this plugin together 'phonegap-plugin-push' - just to catch some new feature that exposed by @md repo (see push actions...).

Diagnostic plugin doesn't allow to know if permission was request or not ( like the 'not_determined' response of 'cordova.plugins.diagnostic.getRemoteNotificationsAuthorizationStatus' method available ONLY for iOS).

Strangely, when the app is installed for the first time (Android), permission for push is set to 'true' ( even if no one modal was shown ) -- tested onto android 8.1.0 .

Instead, if we use the 'RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH' value of cordova.plugins.diagnostic.permissionStatus object, like in the example provided here https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova.plugins.diagnostic#requestruntimepermission permission seems to be always 'DENIED_ALWAYS'.

I'm very confused about how to manage the 'first' time case for this plugin for Android platforms.